# An error occurred while getting the schema information:: null while connecting cassandra with pentaho

Tags: cassandra, pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I am using cassandra input step in Pentaho Data Integration and trying to connect cassandra with spoon. I am getting the error as shown below.

Please help me to resolve this error.

[image]

Comment: Can you please drag your error pop-up to left or right side so that i can see your configuration prorperly..
as far as i can i guess you have not enabled Use CQL version 3. then check it will work.

Comment: CQL version 3 is enabled already

Comment: how have you created your schema?
have you installed python 2.7 ?

Comment: Yes,python 2.7.5 is installed on my system

Comment: I have also created schema with the same name spoon_test

Comment: Same problem here..Did u solve it. I am working on windows with datastax, talend